# How can I get session data into django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to set default value to a column which is getting stored in django session. Below code gives an error `get_state_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'` I know the reason for this error. But when I don't give `request` parameter in defined function `get_id` then I don't able to get the `id` value. please help me on this.

```
def get_id(request):
    id = request.session.get('id')
    return id

class Forms(models.Model):
    form_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id= models.IntegerField(default=get_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of doing it from model, I have done it from admin page itself. Below is the snap shot of the code.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    id = request.session.get('id')
    obj.id= id
    super(FormsAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score -1):

One idea is to override the save method.

```
def get_id(request):
    id = request.session.get('id')
    return id

class Forms(models.Model):
    form_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.id = get_id(request)   
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I believe 2nd line in save override function `'You must pass in the request object to the save method.'` is a comment. I try to run this code (removed the comment) I got an error `No exception message supplied
` at line `assert 'request' in kwargs`.